# Can't connect to a mysql database on another server

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a mysql database installed in a server (Server A) with IP Address (eg: 100.100.100.1) and my php application is installed in another server (Server B) with IP Address (eg: 200.200.200.2). When I try to connect to the mysql database in Server A using the mysqli_connect code, I get the error "Connection Refused" when I run the application.

I have already checked and tried including the port number as I read online that I need to use the port number as well

```
<?php
    $servername = "100.100.100.1:3306";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "dbname";

    // Create connection
    $db = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // Check connection
    if (!$db) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

?>
```

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is largely an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: Check that the server is running and that the firewall allows access.

Comment: Change server name to localhost & try

Comment: if you run this from cmd line can you connect to the db ? mysql -u username -p -h 100.100.100.1

Comment: @ElenaRoman. No, it's not working. Whenever I am trying to log into mysql from the remote machine it gives me an error.
Can't connect to MySQL server on '100.100.100.1' (111)

Comment: Well then the issue if not from php it's from the server. Try to do a ping to that ip, if it doesn't work then either you are not using an ok ip or you are blocked from accessing it. If the 2 servers are in the same network better use the internal ip

Comment: @ElenaRoman I got the solution form the post I've been referred to and some hit and trial. In my case, all I had to do is remove the bind address from the mysql config file.